# Python stacked bar chart not being displayed like Excel chart

Tags: python, matplotlib-widget

I am trying to create a stacked bar chart in Python to try and match the stacked bar chart produced by Excel but I can't seem to get it to match the output of Excel.  The Python chart is not showing me values in the A array.[excel chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eGQFd.jpg) [python chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t8MSf.jpg)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def graph2Peak(self):
    A = [-1478, -16411, 5986, 0]
    B = [14933, 29866, 7466, 14933]

    X = range(4)
    plt2 = plt

    plt.bar(X, A, color = 'b')
    plt.bar(X, B, color = 'r', bottom = A)

    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that the second bar is not starting from negative value.[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def graph2Peak():
    A = [-1478, -16411, 5986, 0]
    B = [14933, 29866, 7466, 14933]

    X = range(4)
    plt2 = plt

    plt.bar(X, A, color = 'b')
    plt.bar(X, B, color = 'r', bottom = [0 if l<0 else l for l in A])

    plt.show()

graph2Peak()
```

Comment: Aritesh,  Would you know how to be able to create multiple stacked bar charts into one Figure like the Excel sheet I attached?

Comment: Aritesh nevermind I was able to find some code to help me out.